# How to exit all multiple nested methods at once

Tags: java, methods, iterator

I've been following Tim Buchalka's course Java Programming Masterclass for Software Developers and I've been modifying his program from lesson 118.

I want to update my list at the runtime while using the list iterator (navigate method). The program runs fine, but if I update my list, Java throws an error: `ConcurrentModificationException`

I have come up with the following solution:
Whenever a user performs a modification of the list, other methods run, and update the list and pass it to the navigate() method. By doing this, my program enters multi-level nested methods, and the problem comes up when a user wants to exit from the program (case 0: in navigate() method). User has to press 0 as many times as many nested methods were ran.

My initial idea was to count how many times navigate() was nested, then using for loop return as many times as it was nested. But later I understood it does not make sense

What can I do to exit from the program by using `case 0:` just once?

```
package com.practice;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class List extends Traveler {
    private LinkedList<String> linkedList;
    private String tripName;


    public List(String travelerName, int travelerAge, String tripName) {//it has to have same amount of parameters or more with super constructor!
        super(travelerName, travelerAge);
        this.tripName = tripName;
        this.linkedList = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    public List(){} //it has to have same amount of parameters or more with super constructor!

    public LinkedList<String> getLinkedList() {
        return linkedList;
    }

    public String getTripName() {
        return tripName;
    }

    private void removeCity(LinkedList<String> cityList, String deletedCity) {
        if(cityList.remove(deletedCity)) {
            System.out.println(deletedCity + " has been removed");
        } else System.out.println("Could not find the city you want to remove");

        List.navigate(cityList);
    }

    //adds a new city and update the list without an error
    private void noExceptionError(LinkedList<String> listOfCities, String cityName) {
        ListIterator<String> listIterator = listOfCities.listIterator();

        while((listIterator.hasNext())) {
            int comparison = listIterator.next().compareTo(cityName);
            if(comparison == 0) {
                System.out.println(cityName + " has been already added to the list");
                return;
            } else if(comparison > 0) {
                listIterator.previous();
                break;
            }
        }
        listIterator.add(cityName);

        List.navigate(listOfCities);
    }


    private void loadToList(LinkedList<String> listOfCities) {
        alphabeticallyAdd(listOfCities, "Poznan");
        alphabeticallyAdd(listOfCities, "Gdansk");
        alphabeticallyAdd(listOfCities, "Szczeczin");
        alphabeticallyAdd(listOfCities, "Warszawa");
        alphabeticallyAdd(listOfCities, "Lodz");
        alphabeticallyAdd(listOfCities, "Wroclaw");

        List.navigate(listOfCities);
    }

    private void alphabeticallyAdd(LinkedList<String> listOfCities, String cityName) {
        ListIterator<String> listIterator = listOfCities.listIterator(); //just a setup; doesn't point to the 1st element

        while((listIterator.hasNext())) {
            //if value is greater, the word that is in the list is alphabetically bigger, thus, put it before the list element
            //if equal, it is duplicate! return false
            // else it is less, thus, we have to move further in the list
            int comparison = listIterator.next().compareTo(cityName); //retrieves the 1st value and goes to the next
            if(comparison == 0) {
                System.out.println(cityName + " has been already added to the list");
                return;
            } else if(comparison > 0) {
                listIterator.previous(); //because we've used .next() in the int comparison initialization
                listIterator.add(cityName); //don't use linkedList.add because it doesn't know the int comparison, so cannot properly add!!!
                return;
            }
        }
        listIterator.add(cityName); //adding at the end of the list
    }

    public static void navigate(LinkedList<String> listOfCities) {
        Scanner userChoice = new Scanner(System.in);
        List travelListObject = new List();

        ListIterator<String> listIterator = listOfCities.listIterator();
        boolean goingForward = true;

        while(true) {
            Main.menu();
            int choice = userChoice.nextInt();
            userChoice.nextLine(); //takes care of enter key problem
            switch(choice) {
                case 0:
                    System.out.println("Goodbye");
                    //possible improvement
/*                    for(int i = 0; i <= List.amountNestedMethods; i++) {
                        return;
                    }*/
                    return;
                case 1: //moving forward
                    if(!goingForward) {
                        if(listIterator.hasNext()) {
                            listIterator.next();
                        }
                    }
                    if(listIterator.hasNext()) {
                        System.out.println(listIterator.next());
                        Traveler.setNumberVisitedCities(Traveler.getNumberVisitedCities() + 1);
                        goingForward = true;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("No more cities in the list");
                        goingForward = false;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2: //moving back
                    if(goingForward) {
                        if(listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
                            listIterator.previous();
                        }
                        goingForward = false;
                    }
                    if(listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
                        Traveler.setNumberVisitedCities(Traveler.getNumberVisitedCities() + 1);
                        System.out.println(listIterator.previous());
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("You're at the beginning of the list");
                        goingForward = true;
                    }
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Main.printCities(listOfCities);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    break;
                case 5:
                    System.out.println("Write new city");
                    String addedCity = userChoice.next();
                    travelListObject.noExceptionError(listOfCities, addedCity);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Write the city you want to delete");
                    String deletedCity = userChoice.next();
                    travelListObject.removeCity(listOfCities, deletedCity);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    System.out.println("You have been in " + Traveler.getNumberVisitedCities() + " cities in total");
                    break;
                case 9:
                    travelListObject.loadToList(listOfCities);
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Something weird happened. Try to choose an option again");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're making this way more complicated than it needs to be. Instead of assigning the iterator at the beginning of the `navigate` method, assign it **in the cases as and where it is needed**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to exit the program you can simply call System.exit(n), where the n is an integer return code (the convention being that code 0 means normal execution and other values indicate some sort of error).